# how to attach scroll event to window after scroll animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a div after scroll animation has finished and hide it when I scroll up/down the page. This is my attempt:

```
$('#cta').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#layer, #servicesContent').addClass('active');

    var position = parseInt($('#services').offset().top);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: position - 100
    }, 'slow', function() {
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            $('#layer, #servicesContent').removeClass('active');
        });
    });
});
```

it doesn't work. the active class is removed after animation has finished and not with scroll movement.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure why, but apparently it takes the window somewhere around 20 milliseconds to exit the `scroll` state, at least on Chrome, on Windows. Or it might be a jQuery trick to fire the animation function 20ms sooner, so it feels more natural. (Human eye and mind make connections that take tiny amounts of time and maybe they took it into account).

Anyway, in order to make sure you bind after the `scroll` has ended, give it a full `100ms` to finish and bind afterwards:

```js
$('#cta').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#layer, #servicesContent').addClass('active');

  var position = 120;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: position - 100
  }, 'slow', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        $('#layer, #servicesContent').removeClass('active');
      });
    },100)
  });
});
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/roz4yfyf/).

Please note I had hard-coded a value to `position`, as `#services` is not defined in my example.

Also please note that hiding events on `scroll` is a really bad idea in terms of usability. Users might want to scroll so they view the div better or read it in full, but they will end up hiding it, which would be annoying. I would at least check the scroll event for a minimum velocity or distance in order to hide an element from the screen.

Comment: Your code works at the first time, if you try to press your 'CTA' button at the second time, the scroll event is triggered automatically

Comment: Of course it does. After the first time it ran any window `scroll` event will run the binded function. You need to name it and remove it after you fire it once if you don't want it happening the second time around.

Comment: yeah, all I had to do was to unbind the event =)